# iOS9 - SQlite3_changes looks like broken

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ios9

We have existing SQlite3 DB implementation which works perfectly on the iOS v8.4.1.
On iOS9, DB module failed to work as per expectiontations. On investigating the issue, we found like SQlite3_changes is not provided the count of changes that happen in DB since its last modified.

Does anyone faced similar issue? thank you for the help.....

We defined a method to insert records on demand. The method:
1. opens DB if available using sqlite3_open
2. Prepares the SQL statement - sqlite3_prepare_v2
3. Execute the SQL statement - sqlite3_step one by one till all records done.
4. executes sqlite3_reset and  sqlite3_finalize for each sql statement executed.
5. Commits the transaction - using sqlite3_exec
6. sqlite3_close - finally close the DB.

On subsequent calls we check for DB changes which is always returning 0.

- (int)DBchanges {
  int value;
  if((value = sqlite3_changes(self->_db)) != SQLITE_OK){
      NSLog(@"entries failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(self->_db));
  }
  return value;
  }

Comment: You might attract better attention if you post a [mcve].

Comment: basically, the logic we used is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Please post a small compilable example that shows the problem. This works fine here in the iOS 9 simulator:

```
sqlite3 *database = NULL;
int err = sqlite3_open( ":memory:", &database );
if ( err == 0 )
    err = sqlite3_exec(database, "Create table if not exists MyTable (MyColumn integer);", NULL, NULL, NULL );

// prints "1"
err = sqlite3_exec(database, "insert into MyTable values(0);", NULL, NULL, NULL );
if ( err == 0 )
    NSLog( @"changes: %d", sqlite3_changes(database) );

// prints "3"
err = sqlite3_exec(database, "insert into MyTable values (0), (1), (2);", NULL, NULL, NULL );
if ( err == 0 )
    NSLog( @"changes: %d", sqlite3_changes(database) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have checked this scenario. It works. My point is you need to close the DB after transaction (like INSERTor UPDATE or DELETE). After closing the DB, on iOS 8.4.1 the call to sqlite3_changes(database) will result the DB changes but in iOS 9, this will give 0.

Comment: I don't think that was every officially supported - you were just getting lucky. Once you close the database you can't make any calls on it again without reopening it and changes will have reset.

Comment: Thank you! This helped us identify the level of problem!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) says:

> This function returns the number of rows modified, inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement on the database connection specified by the only parameter.

It will not work if you close the connection and open a different one.